# C++ difference in behavior between cout and printf

Tags: c++

I have the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
void foo(int**p)
{
    int y = 5; // memory for this is allocated, say at address 3000, and
               // that position of memory is filled with the value 5

    *p = &y;   //we equal the value (contents) at address 2000 to 3000;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int* p; 
    std::cout << &p << std::endl; 

    // p points to nowhere right now
    foo(&p); //we pass p's address to foo()

    printf("%d\n",*p); 
    std::cout << *p << std::endl;  
}
```

When I run this code, printf outputs 5 but std::cout prints invalid data. Can anyone explain why ?

Comment: `y` goes out of scope when `foo()` ends, so dereferencing `p` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Define _invalid data_. What do you expect?

Comment: I'm not sure what *"we equal the value (contents) at address 2000 to 3000;"* means but it sounds like you think `p` now contains the value 5? If so, look at `int**p` again and notice that it has 2 asterisks so `*p` is a `int*` (a pointer).

Comment: Important unrelated note: `// p points to nowhere right now` Is not true. `p` points somewhere, but because it is uninitialized you don't necessarily know where it points. You're probably seeing it pointing to null because the stack is being zeroed at start-up, but you can't count on this.

Comment: @user4581301 actually no. As far as the C++ virtual machine is concerned, it does not point to a valid object, which might as well be nowhere.

Comment: @Frank Unfortunately it COULD point to a valid object if for no other reason than the gods truly hate you. The rest is arguing over semantics. I sit in the "Pointer's gonna point" camp.

Comment: This program contains Undefined Behaviour - returns pointer to local variable - so *any* behaviour of the compiled program is correct. You cannot reason about the behaviour of this program since it is fundamentally broken.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's worth drilling down a fundamental misconception you have about C++:

```
// memory for this is allocated, say at address 3000, and
// that position of memory is filled with the value 5
```

That's "true" in the sense that this is how most compilers will interpret the code. But, as far as the C++ language is concerned, it's an **implementation detail**.

From the language's virtual machine point of view, when you do the following:

```
*p = &y;
```

You are saying: "The int pointer object pointed by `p` now points at the object `y`". That's all. The fact that this is done through memory addressing is, again, an implementation detail.

Now, when `y` goes out of scope, `p` becomes a pointer that does not point to a valid object. Dereferencing such a pointer is **undefined behaviour**.
By the way, this remains true even if a new `int` object later becomes allocated at that same memory location.

The fun thing about undefined behaviour is that it's a carte-blanche for the compiler. It's allowed to assume it will never happen, which tends to lead to your program executing seemingly nonsensical instructions if it ever happens.

I guess what I'm getting at is: Unless you are dealing with pointers to `char`, `unsigned char` or `std::byte`, thinking about pointers in terms of memory addresses is really not the way to go.

Comment: Isn't it possible that the OP simply meant to write **p = y; and assign 5 to the pointed value? It might be worth offering this fix as a option and sidestepping all the UB.

Comment: @Jeffrey That would also be UB since the original pointer doesn't point to anything.

Comment: ugh, yeah, I missd the fact that the original pointer was also uninitialized

Answer (score 0):

Ya, this is definitely a pointer problem, not a cout / printf problem.

For people coming from other languages (such as Java) where you don't directly work with pointers, they can cause a lot of trouble. You really need to understand them pretty completely to make use of them. And in this case, you're not only dealing with pointers, you're dealing with pointers to pointers.

In your specific example, method foo() takes a pointer to a pointer. That's fine, but you really need to understand pointers well before you do that.

It then allocates (on the stack, I believe) memory for variable y and fills that memory in. You then set your pointer to point to y.

When your method returns, the stack resets, and anything done on the stack can be trashed. You don't know what's going to happen to it. But in this case, you turn around and call printf(), another function call, which allocates space on the stack -- in the same range that foo() was doing -- and puts new data there. Your pointer now points to that new data.

And that's what you are printing.

Now, if what you REALLY want is to have foo() fill in values, then what you really need is:

1. P should be an int, not int*, and that changes most of the other code inside main.
2. Foo should take an int*, not int**.
3. Your last line should be *p = y, not *p = &y.

In other words, you're passing into foo where to store the value you're trying to return, not where to put an address.

Of course, most people would have foo return your int value :-) But I assume you're trying to better understand pointers, which is why you're doing it this way.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, I was trying to understand pointers.